# Drupal: Create block with custom tpl and variables (render array)

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

### Goal:

- I want to create a block.
- I want the block to have a tpl file.
- I want to pass an array to the tpl for easy "I dont know php" editing.

In the tpl I want to:

```
print render($content['something']);
```

... instead of just print (render) the entire content all at once:

```
print $content;
```

### Approach so far:

- Implement hook_block_info.
- Implement hook_block_view and set $block['content'] to a function which returns a renderable array.
- Create the right block_ .tpl file and print $content['something'].
- Error :(

Now, I can make this work by implementing hook_theme, but I would love to just use the default block_ .tpl. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the .tpl you can do:

```
print render($elements['something']);
```

wee!